# Using logger with two StreamHandlers sends duplicate messages

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-logging

When I enter a new python instance and I try to configure a logger with two StreamHandlers, the output for `logger.error` is duplicated. My code is:

```py
❯ python
Python 3.10.6 (main, Nov 14 2022, 16:10:14) [GCC 11.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import logging
>>> logger = logging.getLogger()
>>> logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
>>>
>>> info = logging.StreamHandler()
>>> info.setLevel(logging.INFO)
>>>
>>> error = logging.StreamHandler()
>>> error.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
>>>
>>> logger.addHandler(info)
>>> logger.addHandler(error)
>>> logger.error("Error!")
Error!
Error!
```

**How can I fix this issue? The intended behavior should be that I only see one message**

#### Stuff I've tried:

- Set propagate to False

```py
>>> logger.propagate
True
>>> logger.propagate = False
>>> logger.error("Error!")
Error!
Error!
```

- Check if I have extra handlers. I do not:

```py
>>> logger.handlers
[<StreamHandler <stderr> (INFO)>, <StreamHandler <stderr> (ERROR)>]
```

- I'm using the root logger, but I've also tried setting a custom one with and the error is still happening

```py
>>> logger = logging.getLogger("testing")
```

- Set a custom format to each logger to see if they are both being called or one of them is repeating. It seems that the error handler is the one causing the repetition:

```py
>>> error.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("%(levelname)s: %(message)s"))
>>> info.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("%(levelname)s: %(message)s"))
>>>
>>> logger.error("Big error")
ERROR: Big error
ERROR: Big error
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `logging.Filter` to strong check each handler.

```
import logging


class ErrorFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        return record.levelno >= logging.ERROR

class InfoFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        return record.levelno == logging.INFO


logger = logging.getLogger('test')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

info = logging.StreamHandler()
info.setLevel(logging.INFO)
info.addFilter(InfoFilter())

error = logging.StreamHandler()
error.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
error.addFilter(ErrorFilter())

logger.addHandler(info)
logger.addHandler(error)

logger.info("Info!")
logger.error("Error!")
```

Output:

```
Info!
Error!
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need 2 different handlers, use [@FirstShanti's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75698649/5446749)

However, I don't think you need 2 different handlers since you 2 handlers do the exact same thing, only with a different level. Only using one should be sufficient in your case.

This is better:

```py
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

streamhandler = logging.StreamHandler()
streamhandler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(streamhandler)

logger.debug("Debug!")
logger.info("Info!")
logger.warning("Warning!")
logger.error("Error!")
```

returns:

```
Info!
Warning!
Error!
```

The `level` used inside loggers and handlers mean that any LogRecord with a level **superior or equal** would be handled by the logger and the handler.

In your case, the handler called `info` will handle INFO, WARNING, ERROR and CRITICAL messages. The handler called `error` will handle ERROR and CRITICAL messages. You see a duplicate "Error!" because you have 2 different handlers that handle ERROR messages (`error` and `info` handlers).

It is not necessary in most cases to have a handler handle only a specific level of message. What you generally need is a handler handling any message as important as the specified level or more.

---

Also, you specified trying to use `logger.propagate = False`. This is useless here because this attribute makes the logger propagate the messages to the parent logger. However, `logger` is the root logger and does not have a parent logger!